# Why in sql server can't return proper error in decimal data type conversion?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, casting, string-concatenation

When I write query like

```sql
Select 3 + '44. 5'
```

It gave me error conversion failed when converting varchar value to '44. 6' to data type int

Why it can not return proper error for decimal cannot converting to int.

Comment: Enclosing a number in single quotes `''` makes it a string, not a number.

Comment: Data type precedence `Select 3 + '44. 5'` => Conversion to INT, `select 3.0 + '44. 5' ` => Conversion to numeric. **'44. 5'** is invalid INT/Numeric literal

Comment: Because that's not the proper error. `SELECT 3 + 44.5` would work fine because `INT` can be promoted to `DECIMAL`. `SELECT 3.0 + '44. 5'` would give an error about `VARCHAR` not converting to `NUMERIC`. Under no circumstance save overflow will you get an error for converting `DECIMAL` to `INT`, because this conversion is allowed (with implicit rounding).

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59251675/why-in-sql-server-cant-return-proper-error-in-decimal-data-type-conversion#comment104713147_59251675) And if it was a valid numeric literal, `44.5`, you would still get "Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric" because `3.0` would have set the expression type to `numeric(2,1)` and 44.5 is `numeric(3,1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quote. The quote means that it is a string value not a real number value.

```
SELECT 3 + 44.5
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible outputs you might want: `47.5` as a number, or `344.5` as a string:

```sql
    SELECT 3 +  CAST( '44.5' as decimal(3,1))
```

OR...

```sql
    SELECT CONCAT(CAST(3 as varchar), '44.5')
```

Answer (score 0):

First, this page will tell you everything you need to know about this topic (and can be used to cure insomnia): [Data type conversion (Database Engine)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)

Next, what you posted is `'44. 5'` that cant be converted into a number. This fails no matter what numeric data type you try:

```
SELECT CAST('44. 5' AS NUMERIC)
```

This will fail because SQL can't determine if you're aggregating numbers or concatenating text:

```
Select 3 + '44.6';
```

These will work for math:

```
Select 3 + 44.5;
Select 3 + CAST('44.5' AS DECIMAL(3,1));
Select CAST(3 AS DECIMAL(3,1)) + '44.5';
```

These will work for concatination:

```
Select '3' + '44.5';
Select CAST(3 AS VARCHAR(10)) + '44.5'
Select CONCAT(3, '44.5');
```

Comment: The statement that "SQL can't determine if you're aggregating numbers or concatenating text" for the second case is not correct. The implicit promotion rules mean that SQL Server will attempt to convert `44.6` to `INT` (the type of `3`), which fails as then the decimal point is not allowed. There's no confusion (to the engine, at least) on what's being attempted there: `SELECT 3 + '44'` is allowed, and is unambiguously `47`, not `344` (and note that the order of operands doesn't matter for typing: `'3' + 44` is also `47`).

Comment: @JeroenMostert - agreed. Thanks for the correction.  I did a poor job phrasing what I was trying to say.. My point was that the OP's syntax does not correctly tell the SQL engine what it is that they were trying to do.